# Why are my nested loops printing an extra space at the end of the loops?

Tags: java, nested-loops

For every number I print, I want that many spaces of indent before the number. for some reason after the last number, it prints another line with the next number of spaces.

```
  userNum  = 3;

  for(i=0; i<=userNum; ++i) {
     System.out.println(i);
        for( j=0; j<=i; ++j) {
        System.out.print(" ");  
        }
  }
```

Comment: Have you walked through the loop in your head step by step? Start small. Say your `userNum` is `1`. What will happen?

Comment: Please research the difference between `j<=i` and `j<i`.

Comment: You start at `0` and go to `i` (because of `<=`).  So, say `i = 2`, then you have `j = 0, 1, 2` (which equates to 3 values, i.e. 3 spaces being printed).

Comment: "I want that many spaces of indent before the number." But your code prints spaces after it prints the number.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi That just adds a space after the second number printed.

Comment: @Radiodef can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing j<=1 to j<1:

```
userNum  = 3;

for(i=0; i<=userNum; ++i) {
 System.out.println(i);
 for( j=0; j<i; ++j) {
  System.out.print(" ");  
 }
}
```

This should only print the spaces up until j = (userNum - 1) in this case, 2.

Comment: I tried that. Removing the = makes it so that it doesn't print spaces until after the second number printed.

Comment: Ahh true, because in the beginning, both would be 0. You could start j at -1 or start i at 1.